# Adding title attrribute with jQuery in an Accordian

Tags: jquery, html

I have an accordian and I am trying to add a title attribute to the link for people with screen reader. I am using jQuery Mobile and not sure if it is interfering with the . The issue is that it doesn't work. Here is the script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordionContent h3 a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("class") == "accordionLink on") {
            $(this).prop("title", $(this).text() + ", Submenu Open");
            $(this).next().show();
        } else {
            $(this).prop("title", $(this).text() + ", Submenu Closed");
            $(this).next().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="accordianContent" data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3><a href="#" title="" style="text-decoration:none;">JSON Tutorial</a></h3>
            <p>Getting started with JSON</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3><a href="#" title="" style="text-decoration:none;">WordPress Newbie Tips</a></h3>
            <p>Tips for the beginning WordPress user</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3><a href="#" title="" style="text-decoration:none;">Domain name tips</a></h3>
            <p>Tips for getting a good domain name</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3><a href="#" title="" style="text-decoration:none;">Subdomain Advantages</a></h3>
            <p>How and why to using a subdomain</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `.attr` instead of `.prop`?

There are cases when one of them is preferred over the other one, you can read more here: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and didn't work. I'm wondering if I am getting down to the title attribute.